# Authenticating to spring cloud data flow using UAA token - stuck at 401

Tags: curl, spring-cloud-dataflow

Am attempting to authenticate to scdf server using tokens returned by UAA server. I can't seem to get anything but a 401.

I've tried sending the tokens using **curl** too - same result.

(curl) tokens are created using values obtained via [this](https://docs.pivotal.io/scdf/1-7/api-access.html#setting-dependent-services) process.

Tokens are tested against scdf server as

> curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" <dataflow-url from above link> -H 'Accept: application/json"

Im not even sure how to debug this on the server side.

Server is setup using params like [these](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-security-oauth2).

Any suggestions on where to look?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running SCDF OSS using a local `manifest.yml` file, you may want to review the OAuth2 properties that you have it configured with this [sample](https://github.com/jvalkeal/randomstuff/tree/master/dataflow-uaa).

Though this sample is set up to run locally, the configs should pretty much be similar to what you'd want to run it on CF, too.

The other thing to validate is to make sure whether these calls are even going to CF Router and UAA with correct properties; perhaps check their logs to be sure also.